# How to solve a minimize problem with maximize a subproblem

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization

I have a minimization problem 
$$\min_{x, y} \{f(x, y) + \max_{y} g(y)\}$$
which has a max subproblem inside it.

How to solve it? Will alternating optimizing converge to the optimum?

Comment: Well $\max\limits_{y}g(y)$ is just a constant, so you can just solve $\min\limits_{x,\, y} f(x,y)$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth While the second part is a constant? If $y^*$ is optimal of the second part, but it possibly won't be optimal of the entire problem, right?

Comment: The second part is referring to the maximum value of $g(y)$, right? This is just some number (a constant). For example, if $g(y)$ were the function $3.2-y^{2}$, then the second part would just be the number $3.2$ (maximum value of $g(y)$).

Answer (score 1):

As it is stated, the choice of the variable $y$ in the inner $max$ problem is without meaning and could be replaced by $z$ for instance to give $\max_z{ g(z)}$, this is the case referred to by @Minus One-Twelfth. If you want to restrict the value of the $y$ solution to be the same in the outer and inner optimization problem, you should add this constraint explicitly as follows: 
$$\min_{x, y} \{f(x, y) + \max_{z} \{g(z):z=y\}\} \\
= \min_{x, y} \{f(x, y) + h(y)\}. $$